# Как изменить глобальной форматирование даты в mssql/mssql_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, sql-server

Суть в чём: есть БД *MSSQL* и запрос в *PHP*, результат которого извлекается за счет `mssql_fetch_assoc`. Так вот на разных серверах дата в выборке приходит в разных форматах:

Например дата `2017-03-01 18:40:15.817` на одном сервере может выдавать ответ именно в таком формате, т.е.

```
2017-03-01 18:40:15.817
```

на другом, внезапно

```
мар 1 2017 06:40:15:817
```

От чего это зависит? От настроек в БД? От настроек в PHP? От настроек в сервере? Как выдавать дату всегда в едином формате без принудительной конвертации в самом запросе в виде:

```
convert(varchar, field_with_time, 120)  as operation_time
```

Что именно и где это настраивается?

---

### Уточнение:

Один и тот же запрос на разных компах даёт такой результат, а не разные запросы. Вот почему вопрос возник.

Comment: думаю вот это https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189491(v=sql.120).aspx  хотя я предпочитаю всегда явно конвертировать даты в нужный мне формат

Comment: @Mike почитаю спасибо. Дело в том, что один и тот же запрос на разных компах даёт такой результат, а не разные запросы. вот почему вопрос.... поэтому я не знаю то ли это сервер, то ли в php настройки

Comment: А тип данных выбираемых колонок одинаков ?

Comment: @Mike да, конечно. Если это один и тот же запрос, то логично что тип совпадает)) ..... то есть запрос `SELECT TOP 15 field_time  FROM table` и выборкой `mssql_fetch_assoc` - на одном компе один формат даст, на другом он же - другой

Comment: Ну тогда точно параметры сессии надо смотреть в первую очередь. Хотя в php.ini то же есть что то про формат дат, но вляют ли эти настройки на получение данных из БД я не в курсе

Comment: @Mike всё-таки дело было в настройках php.ini. Нашёл где. Написал в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл источник:

В итоге в настройках `php.ini` в секции `[MSSQL]` нужно найти параметр:

```
;mssql.datetimeconvert = On
```

и установить значение в `Off`

- On - Возвращает значение в формате SQL сервера
- Off - Возвращает данные в формате YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss